# Slow deployment from NetBeans 11.3 to Payara4/5 due to JMS destination?

Tags: java, netbeans, jms, payara

This question is about developing J2EE with NetBeans/Payara.

Since using NetBeans 11.3, deployment of my EAR-Project to payara is really slow.

**Problem:**

I have about 20 message driven beans in my EJB-Module and for every
single one of it the following output is written to the console
during deployment:

```
End point determines destination name, Res name: javax.jms.Queue, JNDI name: java:global/jms/<queuename>
    descriptor name : <MDB-Name>|#]
```

This would be ok for me if not on every occurence of such a line it takes a few seconds before the
deployment goes on, so deployment-duration is about 120s. It should be about 10s.

**Setting:**

In NetBeans 8.2 and payara 4.1.x it was ok.

Then I upgraded to NetBeans 11.3 -> Slow behaviour.

Then I upgraded to payara 5.201 -> There it worked a few times like a charme, but the next day: 
again, very slow deployment. I really don't have a clue why.

Running on Win 10, JDK 1.8

The Messages are pushed into the queue like:

```
@Stateless
public class MyMessageSource {

    @Inject
    JMSContext context;

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:module/jms/customeredited")
    private Queue customerEdited;
    ...

    private void sendToJMSQueue(Serializable container, Queue queue) {
        context.createProducer().send(queue, container);
    }
}
```

A MDB looks like:

```
@JMSDestinationDefinition(name = "java:module/jms/customeredited", 
        interfaceName = "javax.jms.Queue", 
        resourceAdapter = "jmsra", 
        destinationName = "customeredited")
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "java:module/jms/customeredited")
public class CustomerEditedHandler implements MessageListener {

    @EJB //Also tried @Inject
    private SomeService ...;

    public CustomerEditedHandler() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
       //...do things...
    }
```

**I tried** some settings in the project propierties, e.g. in Build -> Compile.

I tried different configurations of the @JMSDestinationDefinition, @MessageDriven and in 
MyMessageSource i found around the Internet, but nothing helped.

I also tried replacing @EJB throught @Inject.

Does anyone have any ideas or advice for me?

If you need further information, please let me know!

Regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by myself.
If anyone cares what the problem was:

It wasn't a NetBeans, Payara or J2EE issue.
It was caused by the VPN connection to our company I used so I can do home office.
I guess that the server was doing a nice detour through the internet and back again to notice that port 7676 (JMS-Port) is running on the local machine.

Holy cow.

Now I have to find a workaround for that...

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: Did you specify something through a `glassfish-resources.xml` file? Maybe you are hit by something like this: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/4477 Otherwise I would check what you specified as JMS host. Maybe you specified a full DNS name instead of an IP or localhost which would go through the DNS resolver and could take some time.

Comment: Hi Christoph John, thanks for your answer! Yes, I read the article and tried these things. Sry for not writing that. It doesn't solve the problem.
I have not found a way how to specify a JMS host. It always binds to '0.0.0.0'. As far as i understand, it binds to 'all' (or not routable) IP-addresses and, you might be right, so resolving them takes some time. 
(1/2)

Comment: I then tried to set the type of the JMS Service from 'Embedded' to 'Local'. 
That solved the slow-deployment-problem, but caused some JMS-Exceptions, and I don't have time to figure out how to reconfigure all my stuff to get things work again.
At the moment, I disconnect the VPN when I'm developing and reconnect when I'm doing other jobs. :) (2/2)